# Facebook Meta Tags Not Passing to Facebook Through PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, meta-tags

Good day -- I'm currently using Facebook's PHP SDK to share a link (see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/), but when I attempt to customize the image, title and description via the Facebook meta tags, they do not take effect (FB always renders the defaults instead).

Here is my html head information:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
        <title>Share to Facebook Custom Image</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="Share to Facebook Custom Image">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http:...">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.millennialmedia.com/images/home/mmedia-2.png">
        <meta property="og:description" content="add a short description of the page or content">
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="751866978175179">
    </head>
```

Can someone please advise as to what I might be doing wrong? Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Go to [facebook debugger (ex linter)](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and paste the url. That should help debug. Facebook caches a copy and debugger refreshes it. Try that. Another thing that might help as well is clearing your browser's cache as the last solution.

**EDIT SOLVED**

You are using XHTML and XHTML is strict on errors. That was causing the facebook url parser to fail getting the information due to an invalid `<br />` tag  that you are using (`</br>`). Fix that and it will work. If going on with XHTML look here for common [mistakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Common_errors)

I recommend switching to html like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<head prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns# fb:http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

As for your image not displaying issue upload a bigger image bigger from 200x200 pixels if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, thanks for the response. I had the same inclinations you proposed, but unfortunately these didn't work. Facebook debugger shows my url to be clean (it yields no errors or warnings), and after clearing my browser's cache/cookies/history, the issue still exists. If you have any other suggestions, please send them my way. Much appreciated!

Comment: @MatthewHuntley Can you elaborate on what happens? How do you see that the url share is not valid ? You try via pasting it to your fb account ?

Comment: Sure thing. Basically, I'm posting/sharing a link via the PHP SDK. Please note the post itself (i.e. the share to Facebook link) is successful on my FB Timeline, but the image/title/description associated with the post are all the defaults, i.e. what FB chooses automatically. For example, I have a specific thumbnail image I want to show with my campaign instead of the default, which is something I thought I could customize via the "og:image" meta tag, but the tags aren't overriding the defaults. I always see what FB automatically chooses instead of what I want it to choose.

Comment: @MatthewHuntley what is your website? Can I have the address so I can wuery it and see what does wrong?

Comment: Here you go: http://mhuntley.cs.sandbox.millennialmedia.com/utils/richMedia/facebook/MHDir/FB%20Research%20Project/shareToFacebook_customImage.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jimmy, first, thanks for continuing to help me troubleshoot this. Unfortunately, your suggested edits did not solve the problem. I actually removed the "</br>" tag altogether and even copy/pasted your suggested html code, but to no avail (I also tried with my previous XHTML code, but again, no dice).

Comment: @MatthewHuntley you are then still doing something wrong. please validate your document here http://validator.w3.org/ then debug it with facebook. I copied your source code, changed the br and worked. Also if you want as I said create a new document plain with not headers or weird structures. Get a replica of a website's source strip it adopt the metatags and done.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I've run my document through the validator and after making fixes, it only reveals errors that (I believe) are outside of my control, e.g.: 

"Line 18, Column 75: & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)"

Other than that, it's clean. Can you please send me a screen shot of it working? If it's working, the title of the post should be "Share to Facebook Custom Image" and the description should read, "add a short description of the page or content" instead of "Mobile Advertising..." and "Millennial Media provides...," respectively. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewHuntley Later Ill create a hosted page with your example and give you the link to check

Comment: @MatthewHuntley For me it's working fine. Wait appending screenshot

Comment: @MatthewHuntley here you go. It works https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnx8pgphqao2n3y/Untitled.png

Comment: @MatthewHuntley refresh your cache lint it, and retry. For me it's fine. The problem as I said was the br tag

Comment: Hi Jimmy, this is what I keep seeing: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbregiwdjqlhmr1/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-23%20at%2012.59.14%20PM.png

By chance, would you have that link and I can compare the source code to my own? Thanks again!

Comment: The link is from the one you provided! Look at the URL from the pic @MatthewHuntley

Comment: With that link, could you please confirm if you're seeing it work? Because I'm still not.

Comment: @MatthewHuntley please open an incognito window, clear cache, try another computer etc. I am seeing this I posted this https://www.dropbox.com/s/bnx8pgphqao2n3y/Untitled.png

Comment: Hi Jimmy, still no luck on my end. I've tried an incognito window, my home computer and my fiancee's home computer. I'm still seeing the post with all the default features instead of the customized ones. I'll keep researching this. Just to confirm, with this latest link: http://mhuntley.cs.sandbox.millennialmedia.com/utils/richMedia/facebook/MHDir/FB%20Research%20Project/shareToFacebook_customImage.php, you are seeing the customized features? Thanks so much!

Comment: @MatthewHuntley and on google + . Try also google+ to see what it parses. also try appending ?test=1 in your url like so: http://mhuntley.cs.sandbox.millennialmedia.com/utils/richMedia/facebook/MHDir/FB%20Research%20Project/shareToFacebook_customImage.php?test=1